# Regex for CSV with more than comma

Tags: java, regex, csv

I am not a Regex expert and I am looking for a Regex that will return the value after consecutive comma on the same row.

The data looks like this:

```
2016/02/19 04:25:56,User,0.9,0,0,0,0,0.0
2016/02/19 04:25:58,User,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0
2016/02/19 04:25:58,User,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0
2016/02/19 04:25:57,User,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0
```

And I can only manage to split this off after the first command which is the date and time. Here is the Regex I am using:

```
\.*User.*( ? : \d * \.) ? \d +
```

Comment: Your question requires a tad more information about what exactly your goal with this is. What is your desired output?

Comment: Hi Seth, I need to grab the value after each comma so I can chart this using another application

Comment: why splitting by `,` doesn't work for you? or I didn't understand your problem?

Comment: If you're using java, you can use `String[] arr = yourLine.split(',');` Each value of the array will contain what's between the comas, for example: `arr[1]` will contain "User" http://javadevnotes.com/java-string-split-tutorial-and-examples

Comment: So on my side @Kent it is simple but tricky, after each comma after _User_ each of them is a value.

Comment: @user3153614 after you `split(",")`, you got an array, index `0` based. you can just take `array[2] .....`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant amount of columns, you may use the following regexp to satisfy your needs.

```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}),([^,]*),([\\d\\.]*),([\\d\\.]*),([\\d\\.]*),([\\d\\.]*),([\\d\\.]*),([\\d\\.]*)");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("2016/02/19 04:25:56,User,0.9,0,0,0,0,0.0");

   if(matcher.matches()){
       int groupCount = matcher.groupCount();
       for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
           System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is awfully vague in terms of how the data is stored I'm assuming this is data is currently as a string, or multiple. Why not append each data string into one mega string with each user separated by a semicolon, split that into a list with `ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dataStr.split("\\;"))`, then split contents of that list each into their own sub-lists, splitting on a colon?
For instance:

```
"user1:data1:data2;user2:data1:data2;user3:data1:data2;
**split by semicolon**
= [user1:data1:data2]
  [user2:data1:data2]
  [user3:data1:data2]
**split again by colon**
= [[user1][data1][data2]
  [[user2][data1][data2]
  [[user3][data1][data2]
```

That way you can reference the user by index, then their contained data by a sub-index. In practice, it'd look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String dataStr = "2016/02/19 04:25:56,User,0.9,0,0,0,0,0.0\n"
                  +"2016/02/19 04:25:58,User,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0\n"
                  +"2016/02/19 04:25:58,User,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0\n"
                  +"2016/02/19 04:25:57,User,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0\n";

    //ArrayList containing a line of split data
    ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dataStr.split("\\n")));
    //ArrayList of each ArrayList containing a line
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfDataLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();


    //To the end of 
    for(int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++)
    {
        listOfDataLists.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dataList.get(i).split(","))));
    }

    //DEBUG PRINTS---------------------------------------------------------------------
    System.out.println("------------DEBUG-------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfDataLists.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < listOfDataLists.get(i).size(); j++){
            System.out.println("[" + listOfDataLists.get(i).get(j) + "]");
        }
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Here I split the data String onto seperate lines for ease of reading,  then used newline regex instead of the semicolon I suggested earlier, but essentially it's just the same thing. Processing:

```
2016/02/19 04:25:56,User,0.9,0,0,0,0,0.0;2016/02/19 04:25:58,User,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0;2016/02/19 04:25:58,User etc....
```

would just require subbing out the split("\n") for the semicolon, or really whatever your preference may be. If the data is **already** stored as a list of users (possible considering you already have them listed vertically) then hell, you're already halfway there.

The output for this in it's current state is:

```
------------DEBUG-------------
[2016/02/19 04:25:56]
[User]
[0.9]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0.0]
------------------------------
[2016/02/19 04:25:58]
[User]
[0.0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0.0]
------------------------------
[2016/02/19 04:25:58]
[User]
[0.0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0.0]
------------------------------
[2016/02/19 04:25:57]
[User]
[0.0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0.0]
------------------------------
```

I hope this is something along the lines of what you were hoping to get as an answer, as it keeps the data of each user in one list while still keeping that user's data assigned to them as you can fetch users by parent list index, then their data by child list index.

Disclaimer: I'm no jedi master programmer, this works but I cannot guarantee it's the *best* way. It's certainly *a* way however.